# How do you UNION 2 tables based having a primary Key with different fields in either table?

Tags: sql, join, union

Given this scenario:
I have 2 tables, 1 named Books and the other Customers that look like this -

```
Books
----------
CustomerId
BookTitle2

Customers
----------
CustomerId
FirstName
LastName
BookTitle
```

The customers table has a BookTitle field that has the name of books the customer acquired from another Source (or they could be books they can manual enter into that field)

The Books table can have the same Customer as in the Customers table but the book in that table is from a publisher entered book.

How would I write an SQL query to acquire all the records in the customer table for a specific Customer based on the CustomerId and add the record(s) from the Books table to the returned record set?

The end result would look similar to this:

```
CustomerId | FirstName | LastName | BookTitle
CustomerId | FirstName | LastName | BookTitle2
```

I could create empty pseudo fields in the Books table to correspond to the Customers table and perform a UNION but I would want to be able to filter on a specific customer ID **in one place in the query** to acquire the combination of records from both tables

Comment: Select `null` instead of the missing _column_.

Comment: select from (select .. union select..) where userId=..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select CustomerId, FirstName, LastName, BookTitle
from Customers
where ...
UNION 
Select CustomerId, '' as FirstName, '' as LastName, BookTitle2 as Booktitle
from Books
where...
```

Note that `WHERE` condition in the above query is optional and you can use them appropriately.
Hope this helps. Please share your thoughts if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Arun! That works with the exception that it doesn't meet the requirement of specifying only 1 place in the query to designate the CustomerID filter. Perhaps it may not be a way to satisfy that requirement but Ideally I wouldn't want to specify the customer ID more than once to acquire the result